# Can we assign a handle to a cell of an updatable browse widget in progress 4gl?

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

Can we assign a handle to a cell of an updatable browse widget in progress 4gl? I tried using  get-browse-column but it only works for the first data of the column.

Comment: Please explain what you're trying to do. Why do you want to assign a handle to a browse-column?

Comment: I want to change the background color of a particular cell of an updatable browse widget under some condition using handle. so, I want to assign a cell to a handle.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do the trick ("z" is the browse handle):

```
function getBrowseColumnByName returns handle ( z as handle, n as character ):
         
  define variable c as handle no-undo.
        
  c = z:first-column.
    
  do while valid-handle( c ):
    if c:name = n then
      leave.
     else
      c = c:next-column.
  end.
      
  return c.
      
end.
```

Comment: Thank You so much for ur response but this code assigns column to a handle. I want to assign a handle to a particular cell of an updatable browse widget .